# Unexpected response code 401 in volley when i add parameters

Tags: android, api, authorization, retrofit, android-volley

I have an Api that is working fine on postman but not working well in my code using retrofit. The authentication work well when i have no parameter passed in the body but other wise i get error 401

I was using retrofit before, same error then I changed to volley and yet error persist. But when i test with postman, it works fine. 
Note: The TOKEN works well with the API for a call that does have any body parameter

```
 StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, Config.API_URL_DETAILS
                , new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (!response.equals(null)) {
                    Log.i("tag", "lii"+response);
                } else {
                    Log.i("tag", "lii Data Null");
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("error is ", "" + error);
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }) {


            //This is for Headers If You Needed
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                params.put("Authorization", TOKEN);
                params.put("Accept", "application/json");
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            }


            //Pass Your Parameters here
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("event_id", "30");
                params.put("longitude", String.valueOf(3.4));
                params.put("latitude", String.valueOf(6.6063));
                return params;
            }


        };


        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(request);
```

I expect the output to be the api response but the output is response code 401. com.android.volley.AuthFailureError.

Comment: May be Issue in Header so, please check you post form data or json data ?

Comment: elaborate please...

Comment: please,share your postman's body and header Screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused when the request is blocked from the API End Point. The reason could be a malformed request for that,

- Check your request type [GET/POST/ANY OTHER]
- Check the request Header and Body

Comment: then Check the request Header and Body check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468696/basicnetwork-performrequest-unexpected-response-code-401-android-volley-library/37249268